# Region for polygonal frustum?

Tags: graphics, regions, geometry

An example of a frustum of a hexagonal pyramid (a.k.a. hexagonal frustum) from *Wikipedia*:

[image: An example of hexagonal frustum]

Is there a quick way to build one, given the `Region` of two $n$-sided polygon bases?

Comment: Are the two hexagons 1. already embedded in 3D; and 2. always guaranteed to be parallel? At the very least, one possibility is to use `ConvexHullMesh[]` on the points comprising the two faces.

Comment: @J.M. 1) Yes. 2) Yes.

Comment: @J.M. Awesome! Its sibling `ConvexHullRegion` solves my problem completely!

Comment: Please answer your own question, then. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Solution comes from @J.M.'s ennui](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238827/region-for-polygonal-frustum#comment603000_238827). Example:

```
pts1 = Append[0.] /@ N[CirclePoints[2, 6]]
pts2 = Append[3.5] /@ N[CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 1, 6]]
ConvexHullRegion[pts1~Join~pts2] // Region
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Nicely done. $\phantom{}$